# Comparing $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)^2 dt$ to $\int_{0}^{1}f'(t)^{2} dt$ when $f(0)=0$

Tags: integration, inequality, contest-math

This is from an MCQ contest.

> Let $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^{1}$ with $f(0)=0$.
>
> Which inequality is true?
>
> - $1]$ ${\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f(t)\bigr]^{2} dt \leq \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f'(t)\bigr]^{2} dt }$
> - $2]$ ${\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f(t)\bigr]^{2} dt \leq \dfrac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f'(t)\bigr]^{2} dt }$
> - $3]$ ${\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f(t)\bigr]^{2} dt \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f'(t)\bigr]^{2} dt }$
> - $4]$ ${\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f(t)\bigr]^{2} dt \geq \int_{0}^{1}\bigl[f'(t)\bigr]^{2} dt }$

My Thoughts

note that ${\displaystyle  f(t)^2 =\left( \int_{0}^t f'(s)ds\right)^2 }$

$$\int_0^1 |f(t)|^2dt =  \int_0^1  \left( \int_{0}^t f'(s)ds \right)^2dt $$

With Cauchy Schwarz:

$$ \int_0^1 f'(s)^2 $$

Since this was taken from math-Contest MCQ I'm interested to know the fastest way to solve it

Comment: Just to make sure: is this an on going contest?

Comment: nope this is independent question

Comment: 1. and 4.  are  not true (take $f(x)=x$). 2. Is not true (take $f(x)=\sin x$).So only 3. might be true.

Comment: thank u but how we can sure that 3 is true

Comment: (4) is false by putting $\sin (2\pi x)$.

Comment: Aside: I will suggest that the tag mcq is not necessary...

Comment: this is from MCQ so why isn't necessary

Comment: I don't quite see how the question type  (MCQ) would be useful for classifying/identifying the question...

Comment: The tag (mcq) was already deleted from one of your previous questions, please do not reinsert it. While we are at it, please turn to informative titles, the one you chose said nothing of interest about the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions

Comment: i point that in my old version of my post

Answer (score 6):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, since $f(0)=0$,
$$
f(t)=\int_0^tf'(s)\,ds.
$$
Hence, by Cauchy-Scwarz inequality, and domain monotonicity of integrals of non-negative functions,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 (f(t))^2\,dt&=\int_0^1\biggl[\int_0^t 1\cdot f'(s)\,ds\biggr]^2\,dt\\
&\leq \int_0^1\biggl[\int_0^t1^2\,ds\int_0^t (f'(s))^2\,ds\biggr]\\
&\leq \int_0^1 t \,dt\int_0^1 (f'(s))^2\,ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (f'(s))^2\,ds.
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies that 3] is true. As far as discussed in the comments, the other ones are not.

**PS** If I'm not mistaken, the $1/2$ in this inequality could be improved (using the minimization characterization of eigenvalues of $-D^2$) to be one divided by the minimum of the function
$$
\lambda\mapsto \frac{4\lambda^{3/2}}{2\sqrt{\lambda}-\sin(2\sqrt{\lambda})}-\lambda
$$
which is something like $2.467$, i.e. the $1/2$ can be replaced by $1/2.467\approx 0.4053$

**Edit** Explanation of the quotient. The quotient
$$
\frac{\int_0^1(f'(t))^2\,dt}{\int_0^1 (f(t))^2\,dt}
$$
is the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) for the operator $-D^2$ on the interval $[0,1]$. So, if we assume that we have a self-adjoint realization of $-D^2$ then the minimum of this quotient will correspond to the lowest eigenvalue of that operator, when minimized over the right domain. Now, solving
$$
-D^2u=\lambda u,\quad u(0)=0
$$
gives
$$
u=C\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t).
$$
Calculating the Rayleigh quotient of this function, one gets the quotient I mentioned in the PS. Now we need more conditions for the operator to be self-adjoint (typically one at $t=1$). But minimizing the quotient we find a certain $\lambda$, and that $\lambda$ gives a condition at $t=1$. With that condition we have (choosing domains correctly) a self-adjoint realization. Probably a bit more hand-waving is needed if one wants to be completely rigorous, but this is at least an explanation of how one could get that quotient.

Comment: Can you explain why you come up with such functions (the one with $\sin $ at the bottom)? Thanks

Comment: @JohnMa I have updated the answer.

Comment: \begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 (f(t))^2\,dt&=\int_0^1\biggl[\int_0^t 1\cdot f'(s)\,ds\biggr]^2\,dt\\
&\leq \int_0^1\biggl[\int_0^t1^2\,ds\int_0^t (f'(s))^2\,ds\biggr]\,dt\\
&\leq \int_0^1\biggl[t\,\int_0^1 (f'(s))^2\,ds\biggr]\,dt\, (\text{since } t\leq 1)\\
&\leq \int_0^1 t \,dt\int_0^1 (f'(s))^2\,ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (f'(s))^2\,ds.
\end{aligned}

Comment: @mickep When you wrote "something like 2.467", I bet that the exact value of the minimum is π^2/4 ... which is attained with $f(t) = \sin(\pi t/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x$ allows to exclude 1] and 4]. $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$ allows to exclude 2]. So the right answer must be 3].

Comment: who said one of them must be true?

Comment: this kind of mcq need just one unique answer which is must be true

Comment: @uniquesolution  i tired to check ur comment but would you provide it as  answer